# Hover a specific area of an SVG image CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a SVG image (the snipp is shortened) and i want to highlight each `path` when they are mouse hovered.

```
    <svg width="480" height="660" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <metadata id="metadata31">image/svg+xml</metadata>
    <g>
      <title>Karta</title>
      <g id="g4436">
       <path fill="#C5EF6E" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="4" id="Norrbotten" d="m396.27551,46.7125l-6.5,15.875l-5.625,5.0625l-3.43753"/>
       <path fill="#C5EF6E" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-miterlimit="4" id="Lappland" d="m346.77551,10.15l-7.875,1.4375l3.81247,5.25l0.75003,5.0625l-1.375,6.0625l-2.3125"/>
    </g>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

But i can't figure out how to do this with CSS.

This snipp makes `path` ID:`Lappland` change color to `#111` when the mouse is over the whole SVG.

```
svg:hover #Lappland{ 
  fill: #111;
}
```

How can i change color of the specific `paths` with unique ID with CSS?

Comment: [Seems](https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5ops7kdq/)  to work just fine.

Comment: I want it to `fill` when i hover Lappland, not when i hover the SVG.

Comment: Then target the `:hover` when it occurs on the `#Lappland` element. The selector should be `svg #Lappland:hover`. Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5ops7kdq/1/

Comment: Yes yomisimie gave that as an answer, but doesent work

Comment: Did you see the demo i posted in my comment ? it works there

Comment: Yes i saw that demo, it´s the same as i posted. But i don't want Lappland to fill when i mouse over the whole SVG. I want it to fill when i mouse over just Lappland.

Comment: I posted an updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5ops7kdq/1 This will only highlight when hovering over the Lappland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using setting the hover on the wrong element. Set the hover on the specific ID from the svg.

```
svg #Lappland:hover { 
  fill: #111;
}
```